# Encrypting External HD Taking Forever

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, hard-drive, encryption

I'm using LUKS to create an encrypted partition on an external hard drive, and I'm going to use this hard drive just for storage and backing up files, not for dual-booting or anything. I'm encrypting the whole hard drive, 2TB total, and I chose to do the slower overwrite method and I'm beginning to regret it.

So far it's been encrypting an empty hard drive for five hours and I have no idea how much longer it's going to take. I can't even tell if it's working. There's only one of those "processing" wheels spinning around that shows the external hd is doing something, but I have no idea what kind of progress it's making, or if it's making any progress at all.

Should I prepare myself to let this thing continue encrypting overnight, or has something gone horribly wrong? Is there any way I can figure out how much longer this is going to take? I don't think it's frozen but this is taking far too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can take a long time - it is encrypting 2TB of "random" data to prime the drive.  This is much safer than using the drive plain particularly if it had data on it from before.

I can't give you a better idea how long it will take - it will vary heavily based on CPU power, USB speed and drive speed.  I would expect to run it overnight, perhaps longer.